# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser funciona sem referência de id ou classe?

Tags: php, dom

estou querendo utilizar o [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) para retirar certos links de uma página gerada no frontpage o problema que encontrei é o seguinte como o frontpage não gera nenhum elemento html com `id` ou `class` eu gostaria de saber se é possível indicar um caminho para que isso possa ser feito

> a página na qual quero retirar os links não é minha, estou apenas extraindo dados dela

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim. Você deve usar uma propriedade chamada `XPath`, que indica o caminho de um elemento no DOM (document object model).

Para pegar o `XPath` de um elemento, basta acessar a aba Elements do Developer Tools (no caso do Google Chrome), inspecionar o elemento em questão e depois copiar seu XPath:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
>
> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No caso do link acima, por exemplo, o XPath dele é:

```
//*[@id="supertopo"]/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li[1]/a
```

Espero ter ajudado. :)

Comment: o meu XPath retornado foi o seguinte

´/html/body/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div/p[1]/font/strong´

mas retorna 

´ Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\noticias\titulo.php on line 5
Array ´

Comment: É porque o método provavelmente retorna um array de nós, mesmo que tenha apenas um nó. Você deve iterar por esse array.

Comment: desculpe mas não entendi! tem algum exemplo?

Comment: Qual a linha do código que te retorna "Array to string conversion"?

Comment: `include('simple_html_dom.php');
$content = file_get_html('http://www.abresi.com.br/noticia_700.htm');
$elems = $content->find("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div/p[1]/font/strong");
echo $elems;` na linha 5

Comment: @GuilhermeHenrique veja a documentação dele: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/. O método `find` retorna um array, então você precisa percorrer os elementos ou ir direto no índice do elemento com `find("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tb‌​ody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div/p[1]/font/strong", 0)`. Veja se dá certo.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20271/discussion-between-guilherme-henrique-and-rodrigo-rigotti).